# How can I reset user home folder privileges from gui

Tags: files, privileges

I saved my home folder when I moved from 32bit Mint to 64bit Mint.  Next, I installed Mint 18 from scratch, and copied home folder from backup as root user.

Now I can't get home to startup as it needs to be exclusive to user. Message is DMRC error. What should I do now?

Comment: [This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/dmrcErrors) might help. Please give more details if it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to login as root from a `tty`.  Most distros will not allow `root` to boot an X session by himself therefore you cannot do it from the GUI.

If I am not mistaken Mint uses `tty 7` for the graphical display, therefore we will use `tty 3`.  Do the following.

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to enter the 3rd `tty` (if that do not leave the graphical display try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> for the 4th `tty`)
- A login form will appear, login as `root`
- Perform `chown` for the correct user:

  ```
  chown -R <user>:<group> /home/<user>
  ```

After that you should be able to login normally through the graphical display.  Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, and so on until you reach the graphical display.